# Module parameters

Tags: sysfs

I have two modules, let me call them `module_A` and `module_B`.

`Module_A` has a public parameter declared as

```
static unsigned int my_param = 0;
#define PERMISSION_MASK 0777
module_param(my_param, uint, PERMISSION_MASK);
```

I'm looking for a solution to modify the value of `my_param` during the `init_module` function of `module_B`. It should check if the parameter exists, if so `module_B` should update the parameter of `module_A`.

I know that parameters of each loaded module can be accessed by `/sys/module/module_name/parameters/param_name` and modified by `cat` inside the terminal, but I'm looking for a programmatically solution.

Is it possible to use `inode`  to implement such behaviour?